# Перемещение камеры в unity3d после нажатия

Tags: c#, unity3d, камера

Подскажите пожалуйста, как это можно осуществить(скрипт). Мне нужно что-бы камера в unity перемещалась на определенные координаты по осям x и y (например на координаты 100; 150). Я создал пустышку, в нее добавил коллайдер. Как сделать (скрипт, лучше c#) что-бы после нажатия координаты камеры поменялись мгновенно, т.е.камера мгновенно оказалась на этих координатах. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Причем тут объект пустышка? Причем тут коллайдер на нем? Причем тут камера, которая должна куда-то перемещаться? Нажатие на что осуществялется? Ничего не понятно

Comment: скрипт вешаем например на камеру и пишем в каком либо удобном событии `transform.position = someObject.transform.position` где `someObject` ссылка на объект с координатами

Answer (score 1):

Ох... Вообще надо справку читать и самому учится...
Итак по пунктам:
1) Надо создать событие по которому будет передвигаться камера (InputMouseButtonDown) ссылочка https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetMouseButtonDown.html
2) В данном событии прописываешь следующее, если скрипт на самой камере
Camera C = this as Camera; // должно проканать, ну или пропускаем эту строчку, тогда this.transform.position ... ну и как ниже.
С.transform.position = new Vector3(100, 0, 150); // тут можно поиграться
3) Радуешься жизни.
А ну да, еще надо сделать, если скрипт не на камере, тогда:
Если четко есть представление о public'e т.е. камера постоянная и объект тоже, то просто в инспекторе свяжи их. Ну а если нет, то гугли, а то сразу все захотел)

Comment: >>>камера постоянная и объект тоже, то просто в инспекторе свяжи их / А как ? Связать...

Answer (score 0):

1. Создаешь emptyGameObj - пустой обьект (empty object) и размещаешь его в нужных координатах.
2. в нужном месте кода закрепленного на камеру

   transform.position = emptyGameObj.transform.position;

не забудь что сначала нужно обьявить emptyGameObj и найти его на сцене. Никаких коллайдеров здесь не нужно.